# TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined (discord.js)

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

```
const { Message, Client, MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const fs = require('fs')
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports = {
  name: 'close',
  /**
  *@param {Client} client
  *@param {Message} message
  */

  run: async (client, message) => {

    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => ["Customer Services", "Working Admin"].includes(r.name))) {
      const denied = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setFooter(config.FooterTitle, config.FooterLink)
        .setColor(config.EmbedColor)
        .setDescription("`Only Staff members can use this command!`")
      message.channel.send(denied)
    }

    if (message.channel.parentID !== '928333326803140618') {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setFooter(config.FooterTitle, config.FooterLink)
        .setColor(config.EmbedColor)
        .setDescription("`You can only use this command in the ticket!`")
      return message.channel.send(embed)

    }

    const transcriptChannel = client.channels.cache.get("950690898600165396")
    const deleting = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setFooter(config.FooterTitle, config.FooterLink)
      .setColor(config.EmbedColor)
      .setDescription("`Deleting ticket in 10 seconds..`")
    message.channel.send(deleting)
    setTimeout(() => {
      message.channel.delete().then(async ch => {
        client.ticketTranscript.findOne({ Channel: ch.id }, async (err, data) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (data) {
            fs.writeFileSync(`../${ch.id}.txt`, data.Content.join("\n\n"))
            const closed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setFooter(config.FooterTitle, config.FooterLink)
              .setColor(config.EmbedColor)
              .setDescription(`${message.guild.members.cache.get(ch.name).user.username}'s ticket has been closed and logged in the MongoDB Schema.\n\nCheck below for the transcript!`)
            transcriptChannel.send(closed)
            await transcriptChannel.send(new MessageAttachment(fs.createReadStream(`../${ch.id}.txt`)));
            client.ticketTranscript.findOneAndDelete({ Channel: ch.id })

          }
        })
      })
    }, 10000)

  }
}
```

I'm very confused as to what the problem might be, I've run this exact code on a different bot and no errors are shown.

I know this is an error with mongodb, looked at another similar post on stack but the error was with the mongo version, however I'm still confused as what to do because it's working fine on another bot.

Comment: It means `client.ticketTranscript` is `undefined`. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: All messages sent in the channels, is it possibly because embeds aren't read as messages?

Comment: console log "client" and if you have the client then console log the client.ticketTranscript and show us the result